Change product / variant price with custom module or plugin
I have recently upgraded a webshop to Craft 5 and Commerce 5.
All products only have 1 variant.
Prices are recalculated based on the exchange rates of gold and silver.
Since Commerce 5 does not support the single variant layout anymore I have to use the Product::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE event to change the variant price. In Commerce 4 I could do this with JS since the price field was always available in the details panel.
Commerce 5 makes the DB structure for the pricing more complex as well.
I noticed that the price for a product with a single variant is being saved in 3 different places.

defaultPrice in commerce_products
price in commerce_catalogpricing 
basePrice in commerce_purchasables_stores 

I could try to change these values directly in the DB but that feels a bit dirty since there probably is a lot more going on behind the scenes when saving a product or variant.
What would be the best way alter a products price using a custom module / plugin in Commerce 5?
